# If I have a RAID 1, is it better to have 2 partitions or 2 logical drives?

Tags: windows, partitioning, raid, hardware-raid, logical-drive

I have the need to create 2 drives on a single RAID 1 (1 + 1 TB) configuration under Windows Server. I can create partitions using Windows Disk Management, or I can create logical drives using the RAID software (which by the way is an hardware managed RAID).

What do you think is better (and what possible difference are there) between making a single logical drive divided in 2 partitions (so that Windows sees a single drive and I then make 2 partitions) and making 2 logical drives (so that Windows sees 2 different drives) each with a single partition?

I hope I've been clear, here's a "schema":

```
     DRIVE 0   ( [ PART A ] [ PART B ] )   or   ( [ PART A ] ) ( [ PART A ] )   
     DRIVE 1   ( [ PART A ] [ PART B ] )        ( [ PART A ] ) ( [ PART A ] )
                     LOGIC. DRV 1                LOGIC. DRV 1   LOGIC. DRV 2
```

Comment: (Comment because I'm a Linux, not Windows person, so it **might** be different). Hardware raid should be done at the drive level - and from a performance POV this is the way to go - its also OS agnostic. Its relatively low risk, but you do need to be aware that the RAID controller could be a single point of failure - unlike software RAID which will work from any machine.  On Linux at least software RAID 1 is fast and done at a partition level.